# Установка Octopress

Tags: ruby

Доброго времени суток, даже как-то неловко обращаться к вам с таким вопросом, но как установить Octopress? http://octopress.org

Раньше я только сталкивался с PHP, и то на самом начальном уровне, а тут Ruby, и как я понимаю нужен выделенный сервер, или на обычном хостинге можно эту CMS установить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Octopress (как и все на Jekyll и подобных) работает по-другому, нежели Вы, вероятно, ожидаете. Хостинга ей достаточно любого, который может отдавать статические HTML-файлы.

Устанавливаете ее у себя на компьютере. Или компьютерах. Там же пишете содержимое.

Настраиваете деплоймент — указываете хостинг, где будет находиться результат. По умолчанию, [Octopress умеет деплоить](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/) используя git (например, на GitHub или Heroku) или rsync (например, на любой хостинг, где есть SFTP или можно запустить `rsyncd`). Можно [научить его и деплойменту по FTP](http://io.tonkata.com/2012/03/02/so-why-octopress/), так что подойдет практически любой хостинг.

Хотя если не хочется возиться напильником, то можно воспользоваться Heroku. Для отдачи статики (а больше ничего и не будет) вполне хватит и бесплатного тарифного плана. Или GitHub pages.

Octopress переработает записи в статические HTML-странички и зальет/синхронизирует их на указанный сервер.